# How can I activate Mint 3D acceleration on a virtualbox machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, xorg

I do have a Linux Mint 18.3 VM hosted on a window 10 machine.

My VM can not boot when 3D acceleration is set into the virtualbox machine settings. It stays stuck on an empty command line screen.

If I hit alt-f4 to go into command line mode and try to `startx` I get the following error:

`xf86EnableIOPorts: Failed to set IOPL for I/O`.

After looking around, I found a work-around to start the desktop from there. As superuser, I need to **`chmod u+s /usr/bin/xinit`** and `startx` again and it works.

However, each time I restart the machine, I still have to follow the steps above or the same error persists.

Being not very knowledgeable in linux inwards, I wondered it someone could infer a permanent fix from my temporary one.

---

EDIT: I just re-created a VM from scratch on a new disk, with the same setup. I can confirm that it was not specific to the other VM since I have the same issue. Still no 3D acceleration.

I am wondering, why, if there is a workaround, VirtualBox folks have not fixed this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your problem: The Guest Additions which come with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and 5.1.32 do not work properly on Linux guests with 3D enabled. There are updated versions available here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Indeed you are right. It did the trick. I didn't notice that line on the download page. It all works with 5.2.7. Thank you sir :)

Comment: You're welcome, I knew about this because I was on that site just the other day.